# What does `train!()` do in Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

In some machine learning frameworks, the `train` function might not actually do the training itself, and instead just set the mode (i.e. just making sure the model and such are ready to train). Is this the case with the `train` function in Flux or does the `train!()` function actually do the training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Flux.jl docs](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/training/#Flux.Optimise.train!), the `train!()` function does indeed do the actual training. The function signature looks like: `train!(loss, params, data, opt; cb)` where:

> For each datapoint d in data, compute the gradient of loss with respect to params through backpropagation and call the optimizer opt.
> If d is a tuple of arguments to loss call loss(d...), else call loss(d).
> A callback is given with the keyword argument cb. For example, this will print "training" every 10 seconds (using Flux.throttle): train!(loss, params, data, opt, cb = throttle(() -> println("training"), 10))
> The callback can call Flux.stop to interrupt the training loop.
> Multiple optimisers and callbacks can be passed to opt and cb as arrays.

Another example: `@epochs 2 Flux.train!(loss, ps, dataset, opt)` where we do 2 training epochs. You can find more here in the [Flux transfer learning tutorial](https://fluxml.ai/tutorials/2020/10/18/transfer-learning.html).